# Input value retrived always 0 and prevents form validation

Tags: jquery, html, validation, input, event-handling

I have to validate a form using Jquery as part of my assignment due this Sunday. I need to detect if a field is empty and prevent form entry while also putting an error message in a div with id "divMessage". I would like to do it dynamically but noticed the value I retrieve for a field is always zero. I don't know what to do and am panicking. If I can get this bit of logic right, I can do the rest of my assignment fine on my own.

Tried to validate value of input text field (example of one field, "username", given below) with $("username).val() but the outcome is always 0 . I 'm at a loss. I have simplified my form below to make it less confusing to troubleshoot.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Add Movie Form</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
            var name = $("#username").val()
            error_username= false;

            // Prevention of form submission 
            $("#addMovieform").submit(function () {
                  if (error_username=false){
                    return false;
                  } else {return true;
                  }
            });

           //Dynamically add errorMessage in divMessage 
            $("#username").focusout(function () {
                if (name.length == 0) {
                    errorList.append("<li>Your name is required</li>")
                    $("li").eq(0).attr("class", "name_error_1");
                } else {
                    // Remove error message when name has been typed
                    $(".name_error_1").remove()
                }
            })

    });

<script>
<body>
 <div id="divMessage"></div>
        <table id="formtable">

            <colgroup>
                <col style="width: 20%;">
            </colgroup>
            <form action="/action_page.php" id="addMovieform" method="POST">

                <!-- Username -->
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="username">Name</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="movie-username"id="username" 
                  placeholder="Your Name"></td>
                </tr>
              </form>
         </table>
</body>
</head>
```

Hope to dynamically insert a bullet point with message in "divMessage" when username field is empty and then remove bullet point when username field is no longer empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by moving `var name = $("#username").val()` into your `focusout` function, because in your current code, you only get the value of `$("#username")` once, so it never gets updated

```
$("#username").focusout(function() {
  var name = $("#username").val()
  if (name.length == 0) {
    errorList.append("<li>Your name is required</li>")
    $("li").eq(0).attr("class", "name_error_1");
  } else {
    // Remove error message when name has been typed
    $(".name_error_1").remove()
  }
})
```

Also, please note that your `</head>` should be closed before you `<body>` begins

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  error_username = false;
  var errorList = $('.errorList')

  // Prevention of form submission 
  $("#addMovieform").submit(function() {
    if (error_username = false) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });

  //Dynamically add errorMessage in divMessage 
  $("#username").focusout(function() {
    var name = $("#username").val()
    if (name.length == 0) {
      errorList.append("<li>Your name is required</li>")
      $("li").eq(0).attr("class", "name_error_1");
    } else {
      // Remove error message when name has been typed
      $(".name_error_1").remove()
    }
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divMessage"></div>
<table id="formtable">

  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 20%;">
  </colgroup>
  <form action="/action_page.php" id="addMovieform" method="POST">

    <!-- Username -->
    <tr>
      <td><label for="username">Name</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="movie-username" id="username" placeholder="Your Name"></td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
<div class="errorList"></div>
```

Comment: Hello!! Thank you so much :) This helped me a lot! And yes, thank you for pointing out the <body> and <head> errors. It's correct in my original code but since I was copying and pasting, I wasn't paying much attention to the html. Thank you!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The value of `#username` at page load is stored in `name`.

When you change the value of `#username` after the page load. The value inside `name` doesn't change with it.

So inside your function you need need to get the current value:

```
$("#username").focusout(function () {
    var name = $(this).val()
    if (name.length == 0) {
         /* rest of the function */
```

The first `var name = $("#username").val()` then gets obsolete and can be deleted.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is similar to the comment above and it worked :) So grateful both of you took the time to help!